# Why the move constructor nor the move assign operator is not called in this expression with UDL?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, user-defined-literals

I have a class with copy constructor and copy assign operator deleted. Move constructor amd move-assign operator are present. It also defines an `operator<<`:

```
struct S
{
    S(std::size_t s) {}

    S(const S &) = delete;
    S(S &&) { std::cout << "S&&"; }
    S &operator =(const S &) = delete;
    S &operator =(S &&) { std::cout << "=S&&"; return *this; }

    S &operator<<(int) { return *this; }
};
```

Also I've added an user defined literal:

```
S operator ""_S(const char *const c, std::size_t s)
{
    return s;
}
```

Then I use the `S` object like this:

```
/* Error: */ auto s1 = "Test"_S << 1 << 2 << 3;
/* Ok:    */ auto s2 = "123"_S;
```

[The error I'm getting](https://tio.run/##dVA9b4MwEJ3rX3GiEiKkUQrZMHTL3IHukWWcxCqxkX0sQfz10jNNIlG1Hk7W8/s6y67byFaY0zQ9ayPbvlFQauvRKXF5Y4wuvUSo2cCe6sRjUxReX9UBwa9gGFlApTWeKBCvoIJGtQoVDzghBA0wq6TtEcoSojqOIw4jESC2nXICrYPqP5MF52/D6sfRKeydgRTP2gf/hbgsE20waH/TRs5YDY@QKDrcF5Jn4SC93V9guXv4j5uV54zSyB4uQptkftqmsHfOugLSLYgeLfiM9oo@lEdKCL2zMPIwdnwWvH8WQOchyIMgy3fEp473tFceKk/Tlzy24uSnDfWq5Hqdi28) is:

```
.code.tio.cpp:22:20: error: call to deleted constructor of 'S'
        /* Error: */ auto s1 = "Test"_S << 1 << 2 << 3;
                          ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.code.tio.cpp:7:2: note: 'S' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        S(const S &) = delete;
        ^
```

---

I thought that the `Error` case would be valid and trigger the `operator=(S &&)` since `"Test"_S << 1 << 2 << 3` is a temporary expression. Also nothing is printed on the output window but I was expecting to see `=S&&=S&&`.

Obviously I'm wrong on all my assumptions, what's happening here?

- Why `s1` is not move-asigned from `"Test"_S << 1 << 2 << 3` expression?
- Is `s2` created in-place with the `"123"_S` expression thus avoiding the move-assign operator?

Comment: You should mention what the error is, though: https://godbolt.org/z/71hTvnq89 . About the second point, yes, the constructor is called, not the move assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why s1 is not move-assigned from "Test"_S << 1 << 2 << 3 expression?

`operator<<` returns a reference, but the copy constructor is deleted. You might do something like this

```cpp
struct S
{
    S(std::size_t s) { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }

    S(const S &) = delete;
    S(S &&) { std::cout << "S&&"; }
    S &operator =(const S &) = delete;
    S &operator =(S &&) { std::cout << "=S&&"; return *this; }

    S operator<<(int) { return std::move(*this); }
//   ^                         ^^^^^^^^^    
};
```

Which will output<sup>1</sup>

```
ctor
S&&S&&S&&ctor
```

---

<sup>1) https://godbolt.org/z/9Ef6PWz86</sup>

Comment: Returning `S&&` might be an alternative too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e7xo89rT4).